# Is it a bad idea to use multiple segues to go back instead of unwinding?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboardsegue

I have a set of view controllers which are all "push"ed to via `performSegue` from buttons in previous view controllers. I know of unwinding segues, but I am wondering exactly why, if at all, it is a bad idea to simply create another segue pushing back to the original VC? For example, I have VCA and VCB. I push from VCA to VCB by using `performSegue`, and then I have a back button in VCB which performs another `performSegue` back to VCA. I know I could unwind the initial segue, but is there a clear detriment to using several segues?

Answer (score 2):

> it is a bad idea to simply create another segue pushing back to the
>   original VC?

Yes it is, mentioning that "pushing back" is kind of inappropriate term because when talking about getting back to a previous view controller in `UINavigationController` means *popping* to it, pushing would be mean adding a new one. Otherwise, pushing back a view controller doesn't mean that doesn't mean that you will remove the current view controller from the navigation stack, instead you will another one it, to make it more clear consider the following:

There are 4 view controllers in the app, the current one on the stack is the fourth one:

**`A => B => C => D`**

Let's assume that you are aiming to "push back" to "**B**", that's will cause to the the navigation stack to be:

**`A => B => C => D => B`** but *not* **`A => B`** which is usually the unexpected result: for the first scenario popping from the latest view controller ("**B**") would leads to go back to "**D**" meanwhile for the second scenario popping from the latest view controller leads to back to "**A**" which is the natural expected behavior.

**So, What's the appropriate way?**

The [`UINavigationController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller?language=objc) has:

- [**`popViewController(animated:)`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller):

> Pops the top view controller from the navigation stack and updates the
>   display.

which means that it pop the latest (only one) view controller.

Usage:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Output:

**`A => B => C`**

If you are aiming to pop directly to the root view controller ("**A**"), you could use the

- [**`popToRootViewController(animated:)`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller):

> Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view
>   controller and updates the display.

Usage:

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Output:

**`A`**

Finally, if you are aiming to pop to a specific view controller (form "**D**" to "**B**") you would need to iterate through [**`viewControllers`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621873-viewcontrollers) array and call:

- [**`popToViewController(_:animated:)`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621871-poptoviewcontroller):

> Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the
>   top of the navigation stack.

Usage:

```
if let nvc = navigationController {
    for vc in nvc.viewControllers {
        if vc is BViewController {
            navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

**`A => B`**

---

**Back to segues:**

Based on the description above, you *should* use unwind segues. You might want to check:

- [What's the difference between unwind segues and popping to view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874429/whats-the-difference-between-unwind-segues-and-popping-to-view-controllers)
- [unwind segue vs. popViewControllerAnimated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300192/unwind-segue-vs-popviewcontrolleranimated)

Answer (score 0):

Right way to go back in view controller programmatically is to call

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true).
```

If you call performSegue and the segue you perform is ShowSegue, showing VC will be added to navigation stack and if you press "back button" you'll return to VC you considered closed.
So, if you use navigationController its better use unwind segue (if you prefer storyboard way) or popViewController function (if you prefer do it programmatically )